# building Nginx on windows throwing 'zconf.h' not found

Tags: java, visual-studio, nginx, zlib

I am trying to build the nginx on Windows by following [this tutorial][1]
everything works fine but when I enter **nmake/f objs\MakeFile** command it throws following error

\nginx\objs\lib\zlib-1.2.12\zlib.h(34): fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'zconf.h': No such file or directory
NMAKE : fatal error U1077: '"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX64\x64\cl.EXE"' : return code '0x2'
Stop.
but if I search for file 'zconf.h' in zlib folder. I can see it.
I am using Visual Studio 2019 and zlib 1.2.12
Can someone please guide me is it the issue of some dependency?
How can I fix it?
thanks in advance
[1]: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=M-cj-p4rZtU

Comment: How is this question related to [tag:java]?

Answer (score 0):

I moved zconf.h from \nginx\objs\lib\zlib-1.2.13\out\build\x64-Debug
to \nginx\objs\lib\zlib-1.2.13. After that it build correctly for me and nginx.exe can be found in \nginx\objs. Let me know if there are any other issues.